# .NET WebClient : any possibility a certificate or TLS connection is being cached? SSL/TLS error: could not establish trust relationship

Tags: .net, ssl, webclient

I have two .NET desktop programs, each of which uses **WebClient** to pull values from a web handler running on an intranet webserver.  When these two programs are run *on a particular PC*, one of the programs succeeds but the other gets an SSL error: `The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.` Yet when the program that gets the SSL error is run on a different PC, there is no such error and everything works properly. These desktop programs are being launched from the webserver using ClickOnce via its web-publishing mechanism, so the code that executes on various PCs would be the same; it wouldn't be a versioning issue where one machine is running a different version of the program than the other.

The certificate on the webserver was changed yesterday because the old one was expiring. Testing with a browser on the machine that gets the SSL error shows that the browser is indeed using the *new* replacement SSL certificate on that PC and the PC is able to establish an SSL connection with the webserver. So I'm looking for possible explanations as to why one program is getting the SSL/TLS error and the other program is not, on that same machine. Does .NET WebClient do any kind of caching that might explain this situation?

Comment: It's probably TLS session caching. You can clear the cache by restarting either client or server machine.